# Resizing an image within button

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

I'm working on a project of mine and I can't seem to scale an image I added to a button.  I was wondering how I can resize an image that I put within a button?

`This is within the image attribute and not the background image.`

David

Comment: check your content mode of button UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Comment: no contentmode of your button.

Comment: Where is that written, I can't find it in my source code.

Comment: I've been using the storyboard editor to add the buttons.

Comment: in story board check property of your button on right side, you will find it in view--> Mode

Comment: Okay it is set to Scale To Fit

Comment: Also when adding buttons and stuff, where is that written in the project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46775/discussion-between-pawan-and-david-biga)

Comment: you are creating your button in storyboard , then no need to reset its content mode. it should work.

Comment: okay I figured it out.....anyways where does the code go though so you can edit it?

Comment: create a iboutlet of your button object & you can edit its property.

Comment: I'm new to this and learning, how do I do that?

Comment: check out this website for starting up [startup tutorial]http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your content mode of button

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```